# How to make a div invisible without commenting it out?

Tags: css, html

Is it possible to make a div invisible without commenting it out?  If so, how?

Comment: Why do you want a div that you do not want to display? This info could be helpful for the answer.

Comment: @Taz: That's good point but I just went on with what is alternative. Only OP knows whether he really needs to remove them altogether or hide them for later retrieval.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to hide that with CSS:

```
div {                    /* this will hide all divs on the page */
  display:none;
}
```

If it is a particular div with certain class or id, you can hide it like:

```
<div class="div_class_name">Some Content</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.div_class_name {     /* this will hide div with class div_class_name */
  display:none;
}
```

Or

```
<div id="div_id_name">Some Content</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div#div_id_name {        /* this will hide div with id div_id_name */
  display:none;
}
```

**Note:** You need to wrap CSS tyles in between `<style type="text/css"></style>` tags, example:

```
<style type="text/css">
  div#div_id_name {
    display:none;
  }
</style>
```

**[More Information :)](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)**

Comment: I've edited your post twice to fix your `div.div_id_name` typo, and each time you've edited over it :P... I give up :P

Comment: @Matt: Yeah right, did not notice that in copy-paste from class example. Updated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 20):

You can do this by inline style

```
<div style="display:none"></div>
```

or by defining CSS Style like 
In css add

```
.HideableDiv{display:none;}
```

and in your HTML write

```
<div class="HideableDiv" ></div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Its Easy. The only thing you need is, adding a style to it, like following example shows:

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.myInvisibleDiv {
        overflow: hidden;
        visibility: hidden;
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
    }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="myInvisibleDiv"><p>My invisible content</p></div>
```

This div, and it content does definitely not show, and it wont disturb surrounding elements.

Answer (score 8):

if you want it to be essentially gone from your layout:

```
.element_class {
 display:none;
}
```

if you want to just make it invisible (but still keeping it's space seemingly empty)

```
.element_class {
 visibility: hidden;
}
```

and then your element (if a div) would look like this:

```
<div class="element_class"></div>
```

basically anything you add the class="element_class" to will be either invisible or completely hidden.

Answer (score 1):

```
position: absolute;
left: -99999px; /* big number */
```

will make the content accessible to most screen readers but will render the element off-screen.

Comment: wouldn't the browser still have to render it thought? using "display:none" is a much better and less confusing method

Comment: Why the down vote? Just because you may think it's confusing does not mean my suggestion is bad or not helpful. Actually, it's a well-known, standard method when you deal with accessibility. Depending on *why* you want to hide the information, what the information is and how high you set the bar, my suggestion actually would be preferred to display:none.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I misunderstood the purpose of the downvote. forgive me?

Comment: Just a confusion. If we don't want it to display. Should it be available to screen readers for accessibility or something.

Comment: A skip navigation link is perhaps not that useful to those with good eye vision but for a screen reader-user, it makes a page easier to navigate.

Answer (score 1):

May be, its not the required solution, but you can tackle this kind of issues by these little tricks.

You can use `jQuery` to achieve the solution.
If you want to totally hide/show the `div`, then you can use:

```
$('#my_element').show()
$('#my_element').hide()
```

Or if you want that your div become invisible and its still existing in the page, then you can use efficient trick:

```
$('#my_element').css('opacity', '0.0');    // invisible Maximum
$('#my_element').css('opacity', '1.0');   // visible maximum
```